# Different results using filter object and z,p,k implementation

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, bandpass-filter

I'm comparing the output of digital filtering using MATLAB filter object and zero-pole-gain method, and they are not quite the same. I'll appreciate if anyone could point me out in the right direction, and to know what exactly matlab does, because it seems it doesn't use b-a coefficients nor zero-pole-gain method. Here there are my results and the test script (download [data.txt](https://yadi.sk/d/IbNeZ-0-kLfiQA)):

```
srate=64;
freqrange=[0.4 3.5];
file='data.txt';
load(file);
file=split(file,'.');
file=file{1};
data=eval(file);

st=srate*60;
ed=srate*60*2;
data=data(st:ed);%1 minute data
m=numel(data);

x=data;
R=0.1;%10% of signal
Nr=50;
NR=min(round(m*R),Nr);%At most 50 points
x1=2*x(1)-flipud(x(2:NR+1));%maintain continuity in level and slope
x2=2*x(end)-flipud(x(end-NR:end-1));
x=[x1;x;x2];

[xx,dbp]=bandpass(x,freqrange,srate);%same result if use filter(dbp,xx)
data_fil=xx(NR+1:end-NR);

[z,p,k]=dbp.zpk;
[sos, g] = zp2sos(z, p, k);
xx=filtfilt(sos, g, x);
data_fil_zpk=xx(NR+1:end-NR);

f=figure('Numbertitle','off','Name','test_filters','units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 
   1 1],'menubar','none','Visible','on');
plot([data data_fil data_fil_zpk])
legend('raw','dbp filter','zpk filter')
title('raw vs dbp vs zpk')

error=norm(data_fil-data_fil_zpk)/norm(data_fil)*100

d1=fvtool(dbp);
set(d1,'Name','MR_dbp');
d2=fvtool(sos);
set(d2,'Name','MR_zpk');
```

and here there is the result I obtain:
[image]
as you can see, the filtered signals are almost the same. At this point I'm lost at what exactly matlab does.

Here you can see the magnitude response plots:
[image]
[image]
They have the same shape, so they are filtering, but in the case of the z-p-k one, max magnitude is around 60 dB while the other is 0db. Why does this happens? Does that means that zpk is amplifying the frequencies?

Finally, you can the the PSD plot for both filtered signals (first dbp, second zpk):

[image: dbp]
[image: zpk]
Once again we can see the filter is filtering but you can also see a greater value in the first peak of the second plot (zpk filter)...

Comment: Probably `bandpass` does some zero-delay filtering, with a bit different method than `filtfilt`, see the [ImpulseResponse](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/bandpass.html#namevaluepairs) section in the docs. I would go carefully through the documentation to follow what exactly `bandpass` is doing, and perhaps try to explicity give some of the optional arguments. You could also look at the what exactly is going on by typing `edit bandpass`, and see what filter calls are made (stepping through in debug mode could also be helpful).

Comment: Are you just curious to see what happens, or do you really run into problems because of the different filter methods?

Comment: well, i'm trying to recreate the filter in C or GO, i have already implemented using b,a coefficients but is totally off due to the numerical instability. Then I implemented using the sos matrix (from z-p-k) and it gives me something but no quite what I excepted, then I went to matlab and realice that it also gives differences between both methods. I'll have to look deeper into documentation then. Thanks